# Вычисление длины строки без использования strlen()

Tags: c++

Хотел бы задать такой вопрос, как можно вычислить длину строки, без использования функции вычисления длины строки **strlen()**?

Comment: sctrlen - это C, в C++ принято использовать string

Comment: и, соответственно, `string::length`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/

Comment: Раз уж откопали этот ретровопрос, то можно посмотреть, что реализация strlen() может быть и [не столь тривиальна](http://www.strchr.com/optimized_strlen_function), как во всех местных ответах.

Comment: @navi1893, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 13):

Можно. Длиной строки по сути является номер позиции символа '\0':

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {
    const char* cur = s;
    for (; *cur; ++cur);
    return cur - s;
}
```

Comment: а как вывести результат? Просто вот return запутывает меня =/

Comment: Теперь стало все с вами ясно: =)

      return запутывает меня

Comment: @navi1893, my_strlen() это функция. Нужно взять учебник по С/С++, почитать что такое функции и как их вызывать.

Comment: `s` и `cur` нужно местами поменять в конце. Ещё можно, чтобы за границу строки не выходить: `for ( ; *cur; ++cur ); return cur - s;` [Код для цикла тот же получается](http://goo.gl/GwB14T)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, поправил. Грустно, что такое провисело 3 года, да еще и кучу голосов получило.

Comment: @jfs, там выхода за границу не было.

Comment: @Qwertiy Представьте `*cur=='\0'`, тогда после `*cur++;`  как в изначальном варианте в `return`, `cur` будет указывать за границу строки. Сравните с `for (;*cur;++cur)`, где `++cur` не выполняется, если `*cur=='\0'` и поэтому `cur` продолжает на конец строки указывать (на ноль).

Comment: @jfs, да, но оно имеет право туда указывать.

Comment: @Qwertiy "не было" и "имеет право" это немного разные утверждения.

Comment: @jfs, выхода за границу строки _не было_, т. к. указатель не разыменовывается. Он получает значение, указывающее на следующий за концом строки элемент - стандарт разрешает использовать такой указатель (ровно на 1 элемент), если нет разыменования, поэтому указывать туда и использоваться он _имеет право_. Тут нет противоречия, это две разные мысли.

Comment: @Qwertiy: да, выхода за границу в смысле разыменования не было. Фразу *"чтобы за границу строки не выходить"* я неточно применил. Хотел сказать, "чтобы `cur` за границу не указывал".  Хотя, в этом случае, ничего плохого в лишнем `сur++` нет,  так как именно поддержка полу-открытых интервалов в циклах могла быть мотивацией для включения "one past the last element of the
array object" правила в стандарт. (учитывая что код содержал баг c арифметикой указателей, я пытался упростить ситуацию настолько, насколько это возможно—даже если компилятор один и тот же код генерировал бы в итоге)

Answer (score 4):

Можно путем итерирования указателя (с начало строки и до терминирующего символа `\0`) и подсчета числа этих самых итераций - то же, что делает `strlen()`. Но только зачем это?

Comment: поставлено учителем такое, ненормальное, условие

Comment: Вполне нормальное условие, думаю он хочет чтобы вы сами поняли как работает strlen.

Comment: Ясно. Видимо, следующим заданием будет обращение строки "своими руками".

Comment: Прикол будет, если длина строки будет выше чем пара десятков символов. Скажем, миллион символов. Вот за это я и не люблю С-строки.

Comment: Строка в миллион символов? Это ж в какой ситуации такое возможно?

Comment: > думаю он хочет чтобы вы сами поняли как работает

поддерживаю, учитель - умничка

Comment: @AlexDenisov Вполне нормальная ситуация. Насколько я помню ( может где то ошибся ) в файле 1МБ 1048576 символа. Возьмите любой текстовый файл с сотню МБ и получите эту самую ситуацию. В последнее время я с ними частенько работаю )

Answer (score 3):

```
int size_s(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}
```

когда-то я писал примерно так.

Comment: @Илья Михневич, а если в строке есть нулевые символы, но после них есть что-то ещё? "\0" - не всегда показатель конца строки...

Comment: @Kristya, Вы заблуждаетесь.

Comment: @Kristya: Строка C по определению заканчивается на `\0`. Точнее, она заканчивается _перед_ ним, `\0` не принадлежит самой строке. (Отсюда следует, что C-строка не может содержать `\0`). В других языках, даже в C++ — не так, строки могут содержать любые символы. (Для случая C++ я имею в виду идиоматический `std::string`.)

Comment: лучше использовать `size_t`, чтобы избежать переполнения в общем случае, например, в распространённых lp64 и llp64 моделях, где `int` 32-битный, а указатели и `size_t` 64-битные.

Comment: Строка в C таки-да заканчивается на \0, а вот строка в C++ — не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

На 32-битных процессорах так получается быстрее:

```
size_t strlen( const char *s )
{
  const char *p = s;

  for (;;)
  {
    uint32 c = *((uint32*)p);

    if ( (c - 0x01010101u) & 0x80808080u )
    {
      if ((c & 0x000000ffu) == 0) return p-s+0;
      if ((c & 0x0000ff00u) == 0) return p-s+1;
      if ((c & 0x00ff0000u) == 0) return p-s+2;
      if ((c & 0xff000000u) == 0) return p-s+3;
    }
    p += 4;
  }
}
```

Тут предполагается, что входная строка выровнена до 32-битной границы (конечно, будет работать и без выравнивания, но тогда весь смысл теряется).

Comment: Комментарий про [strict aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-strict-aliasing), и необязательно четырёхбайтный uint32_t, и возможное нарушение требований по выравниванию.

Comment: Я сюда этот код размсестил не для того, чтобы его бездумно копипастили, а с целью показать, что строку можно анализировать не только посимвольно, но и блоками по 4 символа (или по 8, если шина данных 64-битная), и это будет намного быстрее.

Answer (score -1):

Файлик main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i = 1;
  for(;i<argc;i++){
    char *pStr = argv[i];
    int length = 0;
    while(*pStr++ != '\0'){
      length++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", length);
  }
}
```

Собираем

```
gcc main.c
```

Запускаем

```
./a.out some_string
```

Будет подсчитана длина всех строк, переданных в качестве параметров (some_string)

Итерация начинается с единицы, т.к. первый параметр всегда имя программы.

Собственно strlen так  работает =)

Comment: а что за **argc** и **argv** тут???

Comment: перменные, которые позволяют обрабатывать параметры переданные в приложение извне

Comment: Хм, наверно вендоводы наминусовали =)

Comment: @1101_debian правильно и заминусовали, зачем у тебя дополнительная операция сложения в цикле. 

Comment: Вы это о length++? Ну простите, хотел понятней написать, а не мегаоптимальней...

Answer (score -1):

Вот таким не хитрым способом можно:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s) {
    const char *p;
    for (p = s; *p; ++p);
    return p - s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну а как же могли забыть это? Хоть и платформенно-специфичное, конечно :)

```
xor eax, eax
mov ecx, -1
mov edi, some_string
mov ebx, edi
cld
push ds
pop es
repne scasb
mov eax, edi
sub eax, ebx
dec eax
```

Answer (score -1):

Способ без циклов и указателей , бесплатно (изначально делал для числовых массивов , но и для строк тоже подойдет , нужно только отнять терминирующий ноль )

```
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY(_array) (sizeof(_array) / sizeof(_array[0])-1)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int number(string chislosimvolov, int i);

int  main()
{
string chisla;
int i;
cout << "\nEnter stroky:";
cin >> chisla;
cout << "Number of symbols in it is: "<< number(chisla, int (chisla.size()));
 }

int number(string chislosimvolov, int i)
{
    int t;
    if (i== -1) t = 0;  
    else
    t = number(chislo,i-1)
;
return t;
}
```