# Кто-нибудь встречал в своей практике sizeof(char) != 1?

Tags: c++, c, c++-faq

Заинтересовался в связи с одним из ответов на недавний вопрос по C++ (C)

[Вычисление длины строки без использования strlen()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/117559)

Я не встречал, и даже не могу припомнить ни одного описания какой-нибудь системы с размером char больше одного байта. Естественно, речь идет о C (C++), а не о Java и т.п.

Заодно, с байтом не из 8-ми бит кто-нибудь дело имел ?

Comment: По мне, так "sizeof(char) != 1" в С++  это то же самое, что и "true!=true" =)

Это абсурд....

Comment: С точки зрения всего багажа Си, такое изменение представить действительно трудно.

Но, в некоторых (старых) машинах побайтной адресации не было вообще.
Символы (для ввода-вывода) упаковывали в машинное слово. Например на БЭСМ (если ничего не путаю) в 48-разрядном слове хранили 8 6-разрядных символов.

 Правда и Си IMHO для них не было. (Сам с такими машинами не встречался, только читал упоминания об этом).

Comment: Плюсую, вопрос весьма интересный и глубокий и срывает покровы с причин того, почему миграция к Уникоду сопровождалась такими муками.

Comment: @avp архитектуры с памятью словами были раньше. Самая прикольная (из того, про что слыхал -- pdp-8 со словом 12 бит. А байт, начиная с S/360 (или чуть раньше) устоялся 8 бит

Comment: Не в курсе на счет char, но на практике работал со структурой (int, short, int). Экземпляры такой структуры писались в файл и, соответственно, выравнивались по 4 байтам, то есть short становился int-ом. Мб, и с char-ом такое будет.

Comment: @RomanoO Комментарий хороший, но на `sizeof(char)` выравнивание все-таки никак не влияет :)

Comment: Нет гарантии, что в **будущих** реализациях C тип char сохранит размер в один байт.

Надо смотреть, насколько критический код лежит ниже проверки.

Comment: Все зависит от опций компилятора, если стоит по умолчанию wchar_t то будет 2-а байта, вообще странно видеть такой вопрос, типы данных могут иметь любую длину на разных системах. Если надо - то есть типы данных с заранее заданной длиной в байтах которые не зависят от реализации, в хелпах всё подробно описано.

Comment: @AlexandrS, а Вы вопрос-то **внимтельно** прочитали?

Сами (в *своими ручками писанных* программах) `sizeof(char) != 1` видели?

Если да, то опишите систему, компилятор и т.д.

Comment: C++ входящий в поставки от Борланда, сейчас вроде Embarcadero называется, в опциях выставляется тип char чему будет равен

Comment: @AlexandrS, интересные сведения о Борланд компайлере.

Кто и зачем минусовал Ваш ответ - не представляю.

Comment: Я лично минусанул. Пока не увижу сам - не поверю. Скорее всего подразумевалось задание типа [`_TCHAR`][1], а это ни разу не `char`.

 [1]:http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/TCHAR_Mapping

Comment: Какие еще *реализации* `C`?

Comment: И еще: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Char

Comment: Вполне возможно. А еще тут недавно появлялся (потом пропал) похожий  ответ про Unicode и VS.

Comment: @gecube Радует определение размера `char` через `byte` :)

Comment: @Котик, а до меня кажется дошло и почему определяют размер через байт и про чипы TMS. Мне кажется, что речь идет о минимально адресуемой памяти и про размер этой ячейки в TMS пишут в 8-битных байтах. 

А когда определяют sizeof(char)==1byte, то **не уточняют** сколько бит в байте.

Comment: Согласен, может быть и _TCHAR там был, так что стандарт пока никто не нарушил

Comment: [C++ FAQ: Can sizeof(char) be 2 on some machines? For example, what about double-byte characters?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#sizeof-char)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- [**C++ Standard - 5.3.3 / 1:**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)

  > `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(signed char)` and `sizeof(unsigned char)` are `1`.
- Более интересным, кстати говоря, является тот факт, что в *C* `sizeof('t')` будет равен не `1`, а `sizeof(int)`.

  > Символьные константы *(заключённые в одинарные кавычки)* по умолчанию имеют: тип `int` в *С* и тип `char` в *C++*. Поэтому в *C* справедливо равенство `sizeof('t') == sizeof(int)`, а в *C++* — равенство `sizeof('t') == sizeof(char).`

Comment: Странно, я рылся в ISO/IEC 9899.1999 и не обнаружил подобного

Comment: @karmadro4 Собственно, эта штука висит на [**`ru.wikipedia`**][1] с референсом на `Draft C++ and ISO C Compatibility`. Не знаю, насколько этому драфту можно доверять, но на практике вроде как действительно так.

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.A1.D0.B2.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8C_.D1.81_C.2B.2B

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, я думаю, что документ заслуживает доверия. Я собственно полез в спецификацию С причине того, что кресты именно оттуда унаследовали эту неоднозначность. Как ортодоксального паскалиста меня коробит, что они не отделяют символьный тип (`char`) от очень короткого целого (`signed char` или `unsigned char`).

Comment: @Котик, спасибо !

Вот про sizeof('t') == sizeof(int) **это может быть важно**. 

Даже не задумывался об этом, видимо интуитивно считал, что sizeof('t') == sizeof(char). А оно вот как вышло.

**Особенно же важно** различие в этом вопросе между Си и С++ !!!

Не думал, что мой праздный вопрос принесет такую ценную информацию.

Comment: И Вам @karmadro4, спасибо !

Сподвигли меня из незаметного комментария ценный вопрос сделать.

Comment: > Странно, я рылся в ISO/IEC 9899.1999 и не обнаружил подобного

@karmadro4, если имеется в виду тезис о том, что `sizeof(char) = 1`, то совершенно правильно не нашли, C (в отличие от C++) не определяет размер объекта типа `char`.

Comment: Asen вас минусанул. Похоже "необоснованное затролливание" его заразило. Наверное, он хочет, чтобы у всех ответов количество голосов было, как у него.

Comment: @GLmonster Не ожидал такого. Я поражен до глубины души и буду жаловаться администрации.

Comment: @karmadro4

> **6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator**
> 
> ...
>
> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
expression or the parenthesized name of a type.
> 
> ...
> 
> 3 When applied to an operand that has type **char, unsigned char, or signed char**,
(or a qualiﬁed version thereof) the result is 1.


http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @gecube, так это же стандарт

    INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ©ISO/IEC

но не все же им следуют? Вот @northerner ведь про реальные чипы

    C2000 and C5000 DSP platforms, a char is 16 bits; on the C3x DSP generation, a char is 32 bits.

от TMS писал.

Comment: Нее.... тут другое. Я думаю, что на *самом деле* для sizeof минимальной единицей является char :-) Т.е. он все меряет в чарах.

Comment: Очень похоже на правду.

Comment: Да, в общем-то так оно и есть:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI_Compilers_and_Industry_Standards

Comment: @gecube `sizeof` меряет всё же в байтах (исходя из Стандарта). Если для какой-то специфической системы компилятор C++ вернет `sizeof(char)` != 1, то это лишь говорит о том, что писать переносимый код не получится. А компилятор грубо (в самой базовой части) нарушает Стандарт языка.

Comment: Ым... Равенство `sizeof('t') == sizeof(int)` в языке С было справедливо во все века и времена. Поэтому откуда вы взяли, что это какая-то новинка "из С99" - не ясно.

Answer (score 54):

Системы с размером char больше одного байта не только существовали, но существуют и активно используются в наши дни. Как правило, это встраиваемые системы или специализированные процессоры, например, DSP. Вот цитата из отчета [Reading and Writing Binary Files on Targets With More Than 8-Bit Chars](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra757/spra757.pdf) компании Texas Instruments, четвертого в мире производителя полупроводниковых приборов:

> On theC2000 and C5000 DSP platforms, a char is 16 bits; on the C3x DSP generation, a char is 32 bits.

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), прокомментирую

> Вот про sizeof('t') == sizeof(int) это может быть важно.

Да, может, но чаще всего разница нивелируется знаковым расширением кода символа до int. Рассмотрим маленький пример чтения одного символа из файла и сравнения с признаком завершения:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if (getchar() == EOF)
        printf("Ох, Щи!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

Запустим, передав программке файл с одним символом с кодом 0xFF:

```
user@linux:~> echo $'\xff' > test
user@linux:~> gcc test.c
user@linux:~> ./a.out < test
user@linux:~>
```

Никакого вывода, и это логично - getchar() возвращает интовое значение 255, сравниваем с -1 (EOF), не совпадают. Однако следующие два примера

```
if ('\xff' == EOF)
    printf("Ох, Щи!!!");
```

и

```
int c = '\xff';
if (c == EOF)
    printf("Ох, Щи!!!");
```

демонстрируют равенство значений, поскольку значение 'xff' расширяется до int знаково (получится 0xffffffff = -1). С одной стороны, это источник ошибок, с другой - такое поведение не порождает несовместимости с C++, где char строго равен одному байту и при сравнении с int будет расширен таким же образом.

Comment: @northerner, спасибо !

Про TMS не знал, а ведь соседи-коллеги системами TI торгуют.

Каким образом gethar(), EOF и приведение char к int с расширением знака связаны с sizeof != 1 не понял.

Самая же типичная (IMHO) ошибка с getchar() и EOF это:

    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { ...

Comment: @avp: `sizeof(char) == 1` сколько бы бит в байте не было. `'a'`  имеет тип `int` в C. `getchar()` также `int` возвращают. Другое дело что машинное определение байта может отличаться от того что думает С компилятор на редких платформах.

Comment: @avp я считаю, что стоит выбрать другой ответ в качестве принятого, дабы не вводить новых читателей в заблуждение. `sizeof(char)` по определению равен 1. А то, что байт при этом может содержать не обязательно 8 бит — совсем другая история.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, согласен. Тем более, похоже, что как сам вопрос, так и ответы на него со временем обрели другой смысл, нежели тот, что озвучен в заголовке (***"видели ли вы когда-нибудь ..."***) (кстати, можете обратить внимание, я не спрашивал ни o размере sizeof(char), ни о стандартах, ни о *наиболее распространенных* компиляторах, ни о том, как сейчас обстоят дела с sizeof-ом .... Т.е. вопрос был об одном, а теперь всеми воспринимается как *"сколько весит sizeof(char)?"*)

Answer (score 20):

Насколько я знаю:

**char** - это единственный задокументированный тип с точным указанным размером. 
Остальные типы имеют относительный размер, например:

`1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`

Answer (score 5):

Может быть выставлено выравнивание по границе `int`, что сделает верным выражение `sizeof(char)==sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Выравнивание для `char` не может быть больше единицы. Стандарт гарантирует что массив `unsigned char` адресует все байты без пропусков. Также у `char` и `unsigned char` одинаковое неравенство.

Answer (score 5):

Столько ответов и только один частично правильный. Нельзя же людей вводить в заблуждение. В стандарте С (6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator)

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
>   signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

и С++ (5.3.3 Sizeof)

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1.

четко сказано, что тип char имеет размер ОДИН байт. Никакая система не может иметь компилятор, который поддерживает стандарт и который вернет в sizeof(char) что то другое. Иначе это нестандартный компилятор!
Теперь о "справедливом" равенстве sizeof(char) == sizeof(int). Не нужно путать значение возвращаемое sizeof с возвращаемым типом, потому что sizeof возвращает тип int и в этом смысле да, равенство может быть. И даже такое равенство может быть 'c' != 0, потому что 'c' будет выровнено до типа int, опять же стандарт. Но, литерал 'c' имеет тип char и поэтому sizeof('c') вернет единицу и, да, типа int.
Далее, язык программирования и его реализация на разных платформах это разные вещи. И если квант хранения информации не позволяет хранить один байт, то тогда, да, однобайтовый тип будет храниться в двух и более байтах в зависимости от минимального кванта информации системы. Но это никакого отношения не имеет к sizeof(char).
Теперь о дурацком примере, который вводит в еще большее заблуждение.

```
if (getchar() == EOF)
```

Естественно, что возвращаемое значение getchar() будет выровнено до int со своим значением, т.е. до 0x000000FF и конечно это не будет равно 0xFFFFFFFF.
Следующий более интересный вариант.

```
if ('\xff' == EOF)
```

А тут мы сравнивает (char)-1 с (int)-1, почему? Да потому что произошла конвертация из char в int и -1 превратился снова в -1.

**UPD: По итогам обсуждения**

**Стандарт С++ имеет понятие байт** и если речь идет об операторе sizeof, то в в этом случае размер возвращается именно в байтах. И хотя в определениях диапазонов и в примерах приводятся значения требующие именно восьми бит, сама **битность напрямую в стандарте не определяется**. Требуется только то, чтобы байт смог как минимум разместить все зарезервированные в стандарте символы.

Что касается самого определения байта, то оно есть в стандарте IEC 80000 и **определяется именно как октет, восемь бит**. Любая документация прямо не указывающая размерность байта основывается на стандарте. Но, стандарт не закон, поэтому отклонения могут быть. Например дополнительные биты могут быть использованы для контроля целостности информации или в других служебных целях, но для пользователя все равно будет видны только восемь бит. Любое другое отклонение это скорее анахронизм.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85565/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey-sv-------sizeofch).

Answer (score 3):

> Кто-нибудь встречал в своей практике sizeof(char) != 1 ?

Дефайны творят чудеса:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define char wchar_t
int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(char)==%d", sizeof(char));
}
```

Выведет `sizeof(char)==2`.

Comment: И где здесь чудеса? Все работает правильно. Если вас это удивляет, то узнайте, как работает препроцессорная  директива #define. 

В вашем коде все **char`ы** заменяются на **wchat_t**. А размерность **WCHAR_T = 2байта**....

Comment: @GLmonster Толсто.

Comment: >И где здесь чудеса? Все работает правильно. Если вас это удивляет

 Я знаю. Меня это абсолютно не удивляет. Я вообще-то сам это написал.

>Толсто.

 А что здесь такого? Вопрос этого не исключает. Вдруг какой-нибудь "программист" захочет таким образом перейти к Юникоду? Так что такое возможно, хоть я на своей практике это и не встречал.

Comment: @GLmonster Особенно круто будет, если сделать такой `global define,` а потом удивляться, что все сторонние библиотеки, включая, возможно, и сам рантайм, отваливаются.

Comment: Если пишется кросс-платформенная библиотека, то нужно быть готовым, что например в char будут запихивать юникод (чего бы и нет). Использовании sizeof уменьшает вероятность ошибок полученых  в связи с 1) размером типа 2) связанных с выравниванием в структуре или в массиве.