# Как записать адрес в char*

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели, адрес

Есть некая переменная `int  a = 10;` для вывода на экран её адреса мы используем `printf("%p\n", &a);`. **А как записать адрес в `char*`?**
Разумеется, что под char* выделена память.

Да, и, видимо, стоит уточнить, что **функциями семейства принтф пользоваться нельзя**. Из доступных функций вывода на экран есть `write(2)`.

Мне же нужно каким-то образом с помощью этой функции из библиотеки `unistd.h` вывести на экран адрес. Я думал, что можно как-то адрес записать в строку, и потом уже выводить.Бол

Comment: Непонятно, что вы спрашиваете.

Comment: если умеете выводить через printf, то смотрите в сторону sprintf/snprintf - они получают буфер и данные туда выведут. А `char*` - это и есть буффер.

Comment: Записать адрес **чего** в `char *`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow 
Я спрашиваю как записать адрес ака "007bf92t4f" в строку char*.

Comment: В каком формате хотите адрес записать? Для удобства программинга можно записать как восемь байт, или в hex режиме будет двенадцать или в восьмеричном или в десятичном или как '1' '0' ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, как выводит стандартный принтф в 16 системе. Возможно вы знаете, как можно сразу выводить адрес с помощью функции write(2) (без записи в char*)?

Comment: С буфером понятнее и быстрее.

Comment: @AlexGlebe , тогда остается открытый вопрос как адрес записать в буфер.

Comment: в ответе весь цикл

Comment: @Laughing_Man: **Строкой** может быть `char [10]`, `char [20]`, `char [100500]` и т.п. `char *` никак не может быть строкой и записать в него строку никак нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал только собственный printf.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x ;
  int * p = & x ;
  char buf [ 15 ] = "0x000000000000";
  for ( int * j = p , k = 13 ; j ; j = (void*)(((size_t)j) >> 4) , -- k ) {
    unsigned int dig = ((size_t)j) % 0x10 ;
    if ( dig < 10 ) buf [ k ] = '0'+dig;
    else buf [ k ] = 'a' + ( dig - 10 ) ; }
  printf ("buf    = %s\n" , buf);
  printf ("printf = %p\n" ,(void *)p);
  fputs  ("no buf = 0x",stdout);
  for ( int * j = p , k = sizeof(void*) * 2 ; k > 0 ; j = (void*)(((size_t)j) << 4)) {
    -- k ;
    unsigned int dig = ((size_t)j) >> (sizeof(void*) * 8 - 4) ;
    if ( dig < 10 ) putc('0'+dig,stdout);
    else putc('a' + ( dig - 10 ) ,stdout); }
  putc('\n',stdout);

  return 0;}
```

выводит так :

```
> ./a.out 
buf    = 0x7ffe43921b40
printf = 0x7ffe43921b40
no buf = 0x00007ffe43921b40
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вам интересен вывод адреса функцией [write()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write) в 16-ричном формате без лидирующих нулей.

Например, вот так:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>  // CHAR_BIT определен здесь


// значение `x` должно быть < 16
static inline void 
print_hb (int fd, unsigned char x)
{
  write(fd, "0123456789abcdef" + x, 1);
}

// для CНAR_BIT > 8 изменения вносить в эту функцию
// для CНAR_BIT == 8 -- поскольку делим байт пополам, требования к аргументам `print_hb()` удовлетворены
void
print_byte (int fd, unsigned char b)
{
  print_hb(fd, b >> 4);
  print_hb(fd, b & 0xf);
}

void
print_addr (int fd, void *a)
{
  if (a) {
    size_t x = (size_t)a;
    int i, n = sizeof(x);

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) // пропустим лидирующие нулевые байты
      if ((x >> ((n - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT)))
        break;

    for (; i < n; i++)
      print_byte(fd, (unsigned char)(x >> ((n - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT)));
  } else
    print_hb(fd, 0);
}
```

Окружающее форматирование -- `"0x"` перед выводом (если адрес не 0) и `\n` в конце (если требуется) добавляйте сами по мере надобности.

P.S.
справедливости ради, программа правильна только для `CHAR_BIT == 8`

Comment: Вродп бы CHAR_BIT не бывает меньше 8

Comment: [бывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/118221/232)

Comment: Где? Я не нашёл ничего

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit#comment3299171_3200969

Comment: @КириллМалышев, да, вы правы. Накосячил среди ночи... (вспомнил, на 4-х разрядном чипе, который я когда-то программировал, Си вообще не было)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вы хотели этого?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int b = 20;

    char string[20];

    memset(string, 0, 20);

    sprintf(string, "%p", &b);

    printf("address of variable string: %p\n", string);
    printf("address of variable b: %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Тест [здесь](https://ideone.com/2LFWYf).

Comment: Вопрос помечен меткой C.

Comment: В C нет такого стандартного заголовка как <memory.h>. Функция memset объявляется в заголовке <string.h>

Answer (score 0):

```
  int x ;
  int * p = & x ;
  char buf [ 15 ] = "0x000000000000";
  for ( int * j = p , k = 13 ; j ; j = (void*)(((size_t)j) >> 4) , -- k ) {
    unsigned int dig = ((size_t)j) % 0x10 ;
    if ( dig < 10 ) buf [ k ] = '0'+dig;
    else buf [ k ] = 'a' + ( dig - 10 ) ; }
  printf ("buf    = %s\n" , buf);
  printf ("printf = %p\n" ,(void *)p);
  fputs  ("no buf = 0x",stdout);
  for ( int * j = p , k = sizeof(void*) * 2 ; k > 0 ; j = (void*)(((size_t)j) << 4)) {
    -- k ;
    unsigned int dig = ((size_t)j) >> (sizeof(void*) * 8 - 4) ;
    if ( dig < 10 ) putc('0'+dig,stdout);
    else putc('a' + ( dig - 10 ) ,stdout); }
  putc('\n',stdout);

  return 0;
```