# Почему первая версия программы на C выдаёт ошибку при выполнении, а вторая исправно работает?

Tags: c

Обнаружил странность. Не понимаю, почему так происходит.
Программа заменяет табы на пробелы, количество которых задано именованной константой SPACES. После чего выводит изначальную длину строки, длину после обработки, а так же саму строку.

Первый вариант программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 32
#define SPACES 4

int get_line_length(char line[]);
int detab_line(char line[]);

int main()
{
    char line[MAX_LINE] = "\thello\tworld";
    printf("[ %d -> %d ]%s\n", get_line_length(line), detab_line(line), line);
    return 0;
}

int get_line_length(char line[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; i++)
        if (line[i] == '\0')
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int detab_line(char line[])
{
    int line_length = get_line_length(line);
    int tubs_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line_length; i++)
        if (line[i] == '\t')
            ++tubs_count;
    int offset = tubs_count * (SPACES - 1);
    if (line_length + offset >= MAX_LINE)
        return -1;

    for (int i = line_length; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (line[i] == '\t')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SPACES; j++)
            {
                line[i + offset] = ' ';
                --offset;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            line[i + offset] = line[i];
        }
    }

    return get_line_length(line);
}
```

Второй вариант программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 32
#define SPACES 4

int get_line_length(char line[]);
int detab_line(char line[]);

int main()
{
    char line[MAX_LINE] = "\thello\tworld";
    int old_len = get_line_length(line);
    printf("[ %d -> %d ]%s\n", old_len, detab_line(line), line);
    return 0;
}

int get_line_length(char line[])
{ ... }

int detab_line(char line[])
{ ... }
```

Первый вариант программы при выполении выдаёт ошибку:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test; ./test 
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Второй вариант работает ожидаемым образом.

На мой взгляд эти два варианта программы эквивалентны. В чём может быть проблема?

P.S.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

P.P.S. Я изначально знал, что функция detab_line() работает некорректно - неправильно рассчитывается offset. Но я не ожидал, что это должно было каким-либо образом повлиять на вызов функции get_line_length().
Исправленная версия detab_line():

```
int detab_line(char line[])
{
    int line_length = get_line_length(line);
    int tubs_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line_length; i++)
        if (line[i] == '\t')
            ++tubs_count;
    int offset = tubs_count * (SPACES - 1);
    if (line_length + offset >= MAX_LINE)
        return -1;

    for (int i = line_length; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (line[i] == '\t')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SPACES; j++)
            {
                line[i + offset - j] = ' ';
            }
            offset -= SPACES - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            line[i + offset] = line[i];
        }
    }

    return get_line_length(line);
}
```

Теперь программа работает. Но очень хочется понять, почему же такая проблема возникла?

Comment: вы бы в двух словах хотя бы описали, что сделать в программе пытаетесь. И да, при желании любой сможет понять это из кода, но вы сможете сэкономить чужое время сразу написав это, более того делать это никто не обязан и многие могут просто пройти мимо такого вопроса.

Comment: Давайте лучше будем вдаваться в детали реализации функций, чтобы получился [mcve] и мы могли повторить описанное поведение у себя

Comment: Да, вы были правы, детали реализации каким-то образом повлияли на ошибку - теперь её нет. Но главное - хочется понять, каким образом некорректная работа функции detab_line() приводила к неработоспособности программы.

Comment: У меня любые варианты падают. Когда вы хотите модифицировать массив с отрицательными индексами `line[-2]=..` из-за вашего просчёта происходит нарушение доступа к памяти и система просто прогу закрывает. *Данные переменной `line` находятся в самом начале стека и вы выходите из границ разрешаемой области памяти.*

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Во-первых, стоит заметить, что я думал, что вызов функций, возвращаемые значения которых служат аргументами для другой функции, происходит в том порядке, в котором эти вызовы записаны в аргументах. Однако, с помощью следующей тестовой программы, я выяснил, что функции в списке аргументов вызываются в обратном порядке:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(void);
int func2(void);
int func3(void);

int main()
{
    printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", func1(), func2(), func3());

    return 0;
}

int func1(void)
{
    printf("func1\n");
    return 1;
}

int func2(void)
{
    printf("func2\n");
    return 2;
}

int func3(void)
{
    printf("func3\n");
    return 3;
}
```

```
$ ./test2
func3
func2
func1
        1       2       3
```

Следовательно, сначала отрабатывала функция detab_line, а затем get_line_length. Ошибка действительно возникала из-за некорректной работы функции detab_line. В ней неправильно рассчитывалась переменная offset - в один момент она становилась отрицательной. В определённый момент это означает, что индекс, по которому мы обращаемся к массиву символов также становится отрицательным. Попытка перезаписать область памяти по данному адерсу в первом варианте приводит к "крашу" программы. Однако, во втором варианте программы перезаписать эту область памяти удаётся, поскольку она была выделена ранее под переменную old_len. Я провёл небольшой экперимент, в ходе которого мои предположения подтвердились.
Изменил функцию main():

```
int main()
{
    char line[MAX_LINE] = "\thello\tworld";
    int old_len = get_line_length(line);
    printf("%p\n%p\n----\n", &old_len, &line);
    printf("%d\n----\n", old_len);
    detab_line(line);
    printf("----\n%d\n", old_len);
    return 0;

}
```

И добавил вывод значения индекса массива перед тем местом, где в detub_line происходит перезапись элементов массива пробелами (то место, где в первом варианте программы возникает ошибка):

```
        if (line[i] == '\t')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SPACES; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\n", i + offset);
                line[i + offset] = ' ';
                --offset;
            }
        }
```

Теперь выделяется память под переменную old_len, а в неё записывается значение длины исходной строки. Таким образом, перед (видимо, память выделяется блоками в порядке, обратном определению переменных в программе) массивом символов в памяти будет находиться эта переменная, что подтвердит дальнейший вывод адресов этих переменных.

Далее выводится значение old_len - для данной строки оно равно 12. Поскольку на моей машине int занимает 4 байта, то в память будет записано: `00 00 00 0C`. Адрес переменной old_len, соответственно - это адрес первого байта.

Далее выполняется некорректно работающая функция detab_line, которая, обращаясь по отрицательному индексу массива, перезаписывает симоволом пробела переменную old_len. Перед каждой перезаписью выводится значение индекса массива. Поскольку переменные типа char занимают в памяти один байт, а символу пробела соответствует значение `20h`, то в итоге в переменной old_len окажется записано `20 00 00 0C`, что в десятичной системе счисления будет равно 536870924.

Результат работы программы подтверждает сказанное:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test; ./test 
0x7fffc2fb706c
0x7fffc2fb7070
----
12
----
12
11
10
9
2
1
0
-1
----
536870924
```

Здесь мы видим, что данные переменной old_len действительно находятся перед данными массива символов line: адрес первого байта line на 4 больше, чем адрес первого байта old_len, что соответствует размеру переменной типа int. Так же видим, что программа перезаписывает данные, соответствующие индексу -1. По этому индексу расположен адрес переменной old_len. Ну и итоговое значение old_len соответствует всему сказанному.

Comment: Замечу, что многие утверждения зависят от конкретной реализации. Например, порядок вычисления выражений `x1`, `x2`, `x3` при вызове функции `foo(x1, x2, x3)` неопределён. Стек тоже не обязан расти вниз на всех реализациях. `char` не обязан занимать 1 октет, хоть `sizeof(char) == 1` всегда.

Comment: @tocic, благодарю за пояснения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если sizeof(char) == 1 всегда, но char не обязан занимать 1 октет, то речь идёт о ситуациях, когда 1 байт != 8 бит?

Comment: Да, с точки зрения C++ байт — это не 8 бит (т.е. октет), а 1 `char`. Смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901666/312941 и https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing).

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо!