# Что такое strict aliasing?

Tags: c++, c++-faq, strict-aliasing

Часто говорят, что тот или иной код невалиден, так как он нарушает «strict aliasing». А что это такое?

Comment: дополнение к ответу @Abyx ---
memcpy нужно тоже использовать с оторожностью, встречал ситуации когда memcpy на архитектуре AARCH64 вел себя так как будто округлял указатель отбрасывая три младших бита адреса на который указывает указатель. Как результат битые данные на границах где доступ на копирование происходил к адресам не выровненным на границу 64 бита(8байт).
Дело было с кодом на С, точно не скажу как назывался источник но в в нем я читал о том что в пользу оптимизации, проверки на выравнивание и пересечение с memcpy были сняты снандартом. Также было сказано, что до определенного момента

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Aliasing** (псевдонимы/наложение/алиасинг) - это ситуация, когда два разных имени (например указателя) обозначают один и тот же объект.

```
int x;
int* p = &x;
int& r = x;
// алиасинг: x, r и *p обозначают один и тот же объект.
```

Это важно для оптимизатора: если есть два однотипных указателя, то после записи в один указатель, значение по другому указателю может измениться:

```
int f(int* a, int* b) {
  *a = 0;
  *b = 1;
  return *a; // в *a может быть как 0 так и 1,
             // оптимизатор не может использовать return 0
}
```

**Strict aliasing** (строгий алиасинг) - это неофициальное название правила, согласно которому алиасинг запрещен для разнотипных объектов.
В стандарте С++ это правило звучит следующим образом:

> [3.10 Lvalues and rvalues `[basic.lval]` параграф 10:](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#10)
>
> Если программа пытается получить доступ ко значению объекта через glvalue типа, который не перечислен в списке ниже, то поведение не определено:
>
> - динамический тип этого объекта, в т.ч. с добавлением `const/volatile` или `signed/unsigned`;
> - тип, *похожий* на динамический тип объекта (например `const int*` *похож* на `int*`, см. [`4.4. [conv.qual]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2));
> - агрегатный тип (массив или класс или `union`), который включает в себя член данных с одним из типов, указанных выше;
> - базовый тип динамического типа объекта (в т.ч. с добавлением `const/volatile`);
> - `char` или `unsigned char`.
>
> (Сноска: цель этого списка - указать случаи, когда алиасинг разрешен)
>
> Объект - это область памяти. У него есть время жизни, тип и может быть имя.
> Динамический тип - это тип наиболее унаследованого объекта, на который указывает выражение. Например если `D` наследуется от `B`, и есть переменная `B* b = new D;`, то динамический тип `*b` - это `D`.

Из этого следует, что хотя указатель на один тип можно преобразовать в указатель на другой тип, из получившегося указателя нельзя ничего читать:

```
char* pc = new char[100];
int* pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pc);  // OK, просто каст
int i = *pi; // ЗАПРЕЩЕНО: динамический тип это char, а читается int
```

Оптимизатор может использовать это следующим образом:

```
int f(int* a, short* b) {
  *a = 0;
  *b = 1;
  return *a; // в *a может быть только 0,
             // у *b другой тип, по этому запись в *b не может менять *a
             // оптимизатор может изменить код на return 0
}
```

Пункт про массивы и классы означает, что к объекту можно обратиться через объект в котором он находится, например:

```
struct S {
  int a;
};

S s;
s.a = 1;
S s_ = s; // Доступ к S::a через весь объект с типом S (довольно очевидно)
```

При этом, код с использованием другого типа не валиден не из-за strict aliasing, а из-за попытки разыменования указателя, полученного в результате `reinterpret_cast`. Стандарт разрешает [только обратное преобразование](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) (впрочем, тут используется термин *unspecified*, так что компилятор может использовать свои правила).

```
struct S2 {
  int a;
};
S2* s2 = reinterpret_cast<S2*>(s);
int a = s2->a; // разыменование результата reinterpret_cast
               // при этом тип s2->a это int, так что strict aliasing не нарушен
```

Для `union` определено понятие активного члена данных, поэтому чтение другого члена нарушает strict aliasing:

```
union U {
  int i;
  short s;
  char c;
};
U u;
u.i = 0; // активный член
short s = u.s; // ЗАПРЕЩЕНО, обращение к объекту с типом int через тип short
char c = u.c; // ОК, char - это особый случай
```

Последний пункт списка про `char` или `unsigned char` - это лазейка для функций вида `memcpy`/`memset`/etc:

```
void my_zero_memory(void* p, size_t n) {
  char* bytes = static_cast<char*>(p);
  for (; n != 0; --n, ++bytes)
    *bytes = 0;  // OK, к любому типу можно обращаться через char
}

int x[100];
my_zero_memory(x, sizeof(x));
```

Однако любые попытки использовать другие типы приводят к неопределенному поведению, например:

```
// НЕПРАВИЛЬНО
void my_fast_zero_memory(void* p, size_t n) {
  uint64_t* quads = static_cast<uint64_t*>(p);
  for (; n > 7; n -= 8, ++quads)
    *quads = 0;  // НЕПРАВИЛЬНО, работает только для массивов (u)int64_t
  my_zero_memory(quads, n);
}
```

К сожалению, в интернете полно такого "быстрого" кода, который в любой момент может сломаться если компилятор использует какую-нибудь оптимизацию после встраивания такой функции. (Правильный memset - это стандартный memset, или его надо писать например на ассемблере, где нет правил strict aliasing).

Поскольку такого неправильно написанного кода очень много, то в компиляторе GCC есть опция `-fno-strict-aliasing`, которая отключает оптимизации связанные с алиасингом.

Comment: А вот в [документации по gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) (-fstrict-aliasing в той же мере относится и к C++) пишут, что такая, как Вы описали работа с union **не запрещена** (valid), но вот  если к полям обращаться *по указателям*, то да, тут уже UB. / (А так, да, полезная тема (+1), кстати, можно еще и про -fstrict-overflow UB написать, вроде недавно где-то было обсуждение integer overflow)

Comment: А т.е. это свойство gcc? И как же в других работать с union? Придумывать что-то пусть замедляющее выполнение, но вправляющее мозг компилятору? Или просто не использовать такие платформы?

Comment: Может быть. Но мне кажется, большинство практиков считает по другому (точнее, даже не задумывается об этом). Поэтому надеюсь, что такая вакханалия оптимизации прекратится (м.б. и стандарт в угоду сложившейся практике придется пересмотреть)

Comment: Не могли бы вы прояснить 2 вопроса - 1. если есть указатель на память `void*`, то как быть с ним? В смысле, приведение к другому типу - не будет ли нарушением? Или нарушением будет только *два* разнотипных приведения? Но тогда вытекает вопрос 2. - если мы полностью забываем об одном типе и далее рассматриваем *только* как другой - то остается ли такое поведение UB или нет?

Comment: @Abyx Я просто пытаюсь понять, реализация вектора в стандартной библиотеке - это strict aliasing или нет. Потому что память выделяется отнюдь не для типа элементов...

Comment: @Abyx В лучшем случае аллокатор может сделать это путем каста к `T*` памяти `void*` (явный вызов `operator new(size)`). Потому что без такого каста он обязан делать `new T[]` - а это уже будет память инициализированная. Вот и пытаюсь понять - этот каст это UB или не UB...

Comment: Я бы тут еще добавил, что `-fno-strict-aliasing` совсем не обязательно исправляет проблемы из-за нарушений алиасинга, ведь не все они вызваны только оптимизациями.