# Присвоить адрес локальной переменной самой себе

Tags: c++

Требуется получить адрес локальной переменной, и сохранить его в эту же переменную. Корректен ли такой код:

```
void* p = (void*) &p;
```

`GCC` переваривает нормально.
Возможен ли здесь UB или нарушение `strict aliasing`?

А также в таком варианте:

```
int* p = (int*) &p;
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/0yLNBN)

Comment: фиг знает, но  MSVS наверняка не даст скомпилить)

Comment: Ну, я бы на всякий пожарный делал это не инициализацией в объявлении, а присваиванием. В остальном - "не вижу препятствий!" (с)

Comment: @Xambey а вы попробуйте - VC++ 2015 совершенно спокой но компилирует...

Comment: @Harry вот [здесь](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c) было замечание, что это нарушает `strict aliasing` поэтому засомневался. Хотя сам не вижу его.

Comment: смешной код )) вот инетерсно в каких случаях такие трюки будут пригодны ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Код для `void*` корректен т.к. тип `void**` приводится к `void*`.

Код `int* p = (int*) &p;` сам по себе корректен, т.к. хотя `&p` имеет тип `int**`, но его можно привести к `int*` через `reinterpret_cast` (C-style cast в данном случае).
Однако разыменовывать `p` нельзя, т.к. это будет нарушением правил [*alising*'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/): `p` фактически указывает на объект с типом `int*`, а выражение `*p` трактует этот объект как `int`.

(И конечно же результат такого `reinterpret_cast` нельзя разыменовать из за правил самого `reinterpret_cast`, но вопрос был про *aliasing*.)

Comment: `strict aliasing` это разве не когда два указателя разных типов на одну область памяти указывают?