# signed int vs unsigned int (undefined behaviour ситуации)

Tags: c++, c, неопределённое-поведение

Если говорить просто и коротко, то меня интересует: количество и примеры undefined behaviour для каждого из этих типов.

Comment: Если именно с типами - то теоретически только переполнение в `signed`.

Comment: @Harry а подробнее?

Comment: Да в общем-то и все :) Просто поскольку представления знаковых чисел бывают разные, стандарт не ограничивает, как поступать при переполнении - ну, там, при добавлении чего-то к максимальному представимому числу, или, скажем, при сдвиге. В то время как для беззнаковых чисел все это определено. Вообще-то, это даже не столько UB, сколько - зависит от реализации. Для меня как для практика, честно говоря, и то, и другое, и третье :) - все просто темные углы, где стоит знак "сюда не лезь". Поэтому и пишу комментарий, а не ответ, что могу в терминологии путаться.

Comment: Для знаковых - решают разработчики компилятора, беззнаковые - просто битовый набор. Вот, в тандарте пишут: **Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in the value
representation of that particular size of integer**

Comment: @Harry вот вы говорите что для беззнаковых определено, а для знаковых нет. Собственно как[ое/ие] представлени[е/я] использу[ется/ются] для беззнаковых, а как[ое/ие] для знаковых

Comment: @Harry с беззнаковыми все понятно. Кстати я все таки залазил в вики и нашел представления знаковых чисел: прямой код, обратный код и дополнительный код. Только вот мне не ясно неужели из-за этих трех представлений весь сыр-бор с undefined behaviour? Если немного углубиться то можно понять что прямой код не используется уже также как и обратный из-за сложности реализации арифметического блока, вроде (надеюсь не наврал). Так смысл тогда в undefined behaviour если остается дополнительный код - единственная реализация знаковых чисел.

Comment: @Harry Кстати про реализацию беззнаковых я так и не понял...но мне кажется что это прямой код, хотя там было сказано если в прямом коде реализованы знаковые числа то алгоритм вычисления арифметических действий усложняется ввиду того что есть отрицательный ноль. ...я в крайнем замешательстве

Comment: прямой это когда `5 = 00000101, -5 = 10000101`, очевидно, что тут возникает нуль со знаком `10000000`

Comment: Вам нужен список их _всех_? Он, боюсь, размером с пол-стандарта.

Comment: @VladD неужели undefined behaviour ситуаций так много?

Comment: @MaximPro: О да! Из тех, которые не упоминались в ответе: использование неинициализированной переменной = UB, разыменование указателя на локальную переменную, возвращённого из функции = UB, снятие `const` с `const`-объекта и его использование = UB, сдвиг на слишком большое количество битов = UB, два вызова `delete` подряд = UB, невозврат значения из функции = UB (а не ошибка компиляции), присвоение одного поля в `union` и чтение другого = UB, вычитание указателей внутрь разных массивов = UB, деление `MININT` на `-1`  = UB, это только то, что вспомнилось навскидку.

Comment: @VladD `снятие const с const-объекта и его использование = UB`? Подробнее, не понял это как?

Comment: @MaximPro: Например, если объект декларирован как `const T`, вы получаете на него указатель типа `const T *`, снимаете с него константность через `const_cast`, и через полученный указатель модифицируете, это UB. А вот если объект не был декларирован как `const T`, тогда UB нет. Но в точке, где вы делаете `const_cast`, часто вы не знаете, был ли объект на деле константой.

Comment: @VladD а можно небольшой пример кода, а то не совсем понятно

Comment: @MaximPro: Ну например: `struct A { int b; }; const A a; const A* pa = &a; const_cast<A*>(pa)->b = 5;` — здесь UB.

Comment: @VladD понятно!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Переполнение при выполнении арифметических операций над типом `signed int` приводит к неопределенному поведению.
- Объектные представления как `signed int`, так и `unsigned int` могут иметь в своем составе padding биты, т.е. биты, не участвующие в формировании значения, а либо выполняющие вспомогательные функции, либо вообще не использующиеся. Комбинация значений padding битов может быть некорректной, т.е. формировать так называемые trap representations. Попытка доступа к trap representation приводит к неопределенному поведению. (Например, объектное представление целочисленного типа может содержать *биты четности*.)

  Язык, однако, гарантирует, что установка всех битов объектного представления целочисленного типа в `0` (в т.ч. padding битов) не может создать trap representation, а всегда приводит к формированию корректно представленного целочисленного значения `0`. С практической точки зрения это означает, что `memset(..., 0, ...)` и `calloc` гарантированно формируют правильные нулевые значения для любых целочисленных типов.
- Преобразование значений с плавающей точкой или значений указателей к любому целочисленному типу приводят к неопределенному поведению, если результирующее значение не помещается в диапазон целевого типа.
- Реализации, основанные на прямом или обратном коде для `signed int`, имеют право запретить использование *отрицательного нуля*, т.е. расценивать представление отрицательного нуля как trap representation. В таком случае доступ к представлению отрицательного нуля приводит к неопределенному поведению.
- Реализации, основанные на дополнительном коде для `signed int`, имеют право запретить использование представления с `1` в знаковом бите и с `0` во всех значащих битах, т.е. расценивать это представление как trap representation. В таком случае доступ к такому представлению приводит к неопределенному поведению. (Другими словами, в 16-битном `signed int` значение `-32768` может быть "запрещено".)

Comment: Почему при выполнении арифметических операциях над типом signed int приводит к неопределенному поведению? Чем это выражается? И почему при unsigned int нет неопределенного состояния?

Comment: И не понятен последний абзац. Что значит запретить использование представления. Как можно запретить использование дополнительного кода? И что тогда получится? Я ничего не понимаю. Объясните

Comment: @MaximPro: "приводит к неопределенному поведению" потому что так сказано в стандарте. А в стандарте так сказано потому, что 1) в рамках разнообразия представлений никакого способа определить результат нет, 2) существуют/существовали платформы, которые отлавливают знаковые переполнения и выкидывают ошибку, 3) еще масса разных причин, которые все и не упомнишь.

Comment: @MaximPro: Где вы увидели "запретить использование дополнительного кода" мне не ясно. Речь идет о запрете конкретных комбинаций битов. Попытаетесь прочитать из памяти такую запретную комбинацию, как значение типа `int` - получите неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Я несколько неправильно выразил мысль.У вас написано trap representation. Что расцеивается как этот "trap"? Цитата: `Реализации, основанные на дополнительном коде для signed int, имеют право запретить использование представления с 1 в знаковом бите и с 0 во всех значащих битах`. Погодите, но это же дополнительный код как можно расценивать 1000 0000 0000 0000 как trap? Я бы понял если бы это был прямой код или обратный, но тут же...как???

Comment: @MaximPro: "Trap" - это исторический термин, обозанчающий "исключение" и/или "прерывание". В чем вы видите проблему с `10...0` мне в упор не ясно. Любая реализация с дополнительным кодом может сказать: у нас тип `signed int` имеет диапазон не `[-32768, +32767]`, а диапазон `[-32767, +32767]` (симметричный). А бывшее представление для `-32768` (т.е. `10...0`) мы резервируем в качестуве trap-представления. При попытке работы с эти предствлением будет вызникать исключение ("trap"). Вот и все. Что тут непонятного?

Comment: А зачем этот trap? Нафига он тут нужен? С таким успехом можно и 1111 1111 1111 1111 в трап записать или еще что-нибудь? Я просто не вижу логического смысла в этом? Зачем запрещать код 1000 0000 0000 0000? Когда сказано что в обратном представлении это число -32768.

Comment: @MaximPro: Во-первых, зачем он нужен - догадайтесь сами. Существует миллион хороших причин иметь "зарезервированое плохое значение". Например, для целей пометки неинициализированных или неактульных значений (отдаленно аналогично тот же null-указателю).

Comment: Во-вторых, где это сказано, что `100..0` в доп.коде - это `-32768`? Каким образом вы это вычислили? На самом деле, нет однозначного ответа на вопрос, обозначает ли `100..0`  `-32768` или все таки `+32768`. Можно привести агрументы в пользу обеих интерпретаций. Одно правило смены знака говорит, что надо взять дополнение до `2^N`. Другое правило смены знака говорит, что надо инвертировать значащие биты и прибавить к результату 1. Оба правила переполняются при работе с числом `-32768` в 16 битах.

Comment: Ну там не совсем -32768, но вот допустим тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) и в доп.коде так и написано 1000 0000 (-128). Что значит:`Оба правила переполняются при работе с числом -32768 в 16 битах`?

Comment: Т.е. ясно, что это представление - "кривоватое". Уже сам факт того, что оно не имеет симметричного положительного "брата" и вызывает переполнение при умножении или делении на `-1` говорит о его "кривости".

Comment: Ну, а что насчет unsigned типа? В каком он виде представляется, я как посмотрю для него нет неопределенного поведения.

Comment: @MaximPro: Беззнаковые типы представляются в *чистой двоичной записи* (pure binary notation). Никакие "дополнительные коды", "обратные коды" и т.п. никакого отношения к беззнаковым типам не имеют - они там нинафиг не нужны.

Comment: И даже прямой код не используется?

Comment: @MaximPro: Ым.. "Прямой код", "обратный код", "дополнительный код" - это все, по определению, способы представления *знаковых* значений в двоичном коде. Все эти представления фундаментально основаны на использовании *знакового бита*. К беззнаковым значениям они вообще никаким боком не относятся и не могут относиться. Хотя бы потому, что там никакого знакового бита нет и в помине.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю ещё несколько примеров неопределённого поведения и поведения, определяемого реализацией в языке C++, которые могут возникнуть не только при работе с целыми числами, но и в смежных ситуациях (например, арифметика указателей).

Битовые сдвиги (далее, результирующий тип — это тип левого операнда, подвергнутый целочисленному продвижению (integral promotion)). ([[expr.shift] 8.5.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift))

- Если правый операнд битового сдвига отрицательный, больше или равен длине в битах продвинутого (promoted) левого операнда — UB.
- Если отрицательная знаковая величина сдвигается влево — UB.
- Если неотрицательная знаковая величина `E1` сдвигается влево на `E2` бит, и значение `E1 * (2^E2)` **не может** быть представлено в беззнаковом целочисленном типе, соответствующем результирующему типу, то UB.
- Если неотрицательная знаковая величина `E1` сдвигается влево на `E2` бит, и значение `E1 * (2^E2)` **может** быть представлено в беззнаковом целочисленном типе, соответствующем результирующему типу, но **не может** быть представлено в результирующем типе, то значение `E1 * (2^E2)` преобразуется к результирующему типу. Результат такого преобразования определяется реализацией.
- Если отрицательная знаковая величина сдвигается вправо, то результирующее значение определяется реализацией.
- Если в результате некоторой битовой операции (не только сдвиги) генерируется trap representation, то поведение такой битовой операции не определено. (C 6.2.6.2 / 4)

Арифметика указателей. ([[expr.add] 8.5.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add))

- Если выражение `P` указывает на элемент `x[i]` массива `x` из `n` элементов, то выражения `P + J` и `J + P` (где `J` имеет целочисленное значение `j`) указывает на элемент `x[i + j]` только если `0 <= i + j <= n`, в противном случае — UB.
- Выражение `P - J` указывает на элемент `x[i - j]` только если `0 <= i - j <= n`, в противном случае — UB.
- Если выражение `P` указывает на элемент `x[i]` массива `x`, а выражение `Q` указывает на элемент `x[j]` этого же массива, то результат выражения `P - Q` равен знаковому целочисленному значению `i - j` типа `std::ptrdiff_t`. Если `P` и `Q` указывают на элементы **разных** массивов — UB. Если числовое значение `i - j` не представимо типом `std::ptrdiff_t` — UB. Стандарт языка определяет диапазон значений  типа `std::ptrdiff_t` ссылаясь на стандарт языка C, согласно которому этот тип должен вместить все значения из диапазона `[-65535, 65535]`. Стандарт не требует, чтобы `std::ptrdiff_t` мог вместить все значения типа `size_t`. ([[cstdint.syn] 21.4.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint), C 7.20.3 / 2)

Указатели.

- Когда время жизни некоторой области памяти подходит к концу, то все указатели, указывающие на **любую** часть этой области памяти становятся недействительными (invalid pointer value). Разыменование или высвобождение памяти по такому указателю — UB. ([[basic.stc] 6.6.4 / 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4))
- Последствия любого другого использования invalid pointer value — определяются реализацией. В частности, в стандарте явно оговорено, что аварийное завершение работы программы при выполнении следующего кода — нормальное поведение ([[basic.stc] 6.6.4 35)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#footnote-35)):

  ```
  int *p1, *p2;
  p1 = new int;
  delete p1;
  p2 = p1; //system-generated runtime fault;
  ```
- Если указатель на объектный тип `T1` приводится к указателю на объектный тип `T2`, и требования по выравниванию (alignment requirements) для типа `T2` не выполняются, то результирующее указательное значение не специфицируется (unspecified). Полагаю, в частности, может получиться invalid pointer value со всеми вытекающими. ([[expr.reinterpret.cast] 8.5.1.10 / 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7), [[expr.static.cast] 8.5.1.9 / 13](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13))

Ну и если речь зашла о неопределённом поведении, то как не упомянуть следующие пункты:

- Требования [strict aliasing rules](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-strict-aliasing).
- [Неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679815/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-undefined-behavour-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85), связанное с неупорядоченностью (unsequenced) value computations и side effects в одном выражении.

---

Естественно, приведённые примеры — это далеко не полный список неопределённых, определяемых реализацией и неспецифицированных поведений :)