# Понять где undefined behavour в арифметических выражениях

Tags: c++, c, c++11, неопределённое-поведение

Довольно таки часто обсуждаемая тема, но тем не менее хотелось бы конкретнее разобраться, где есть `UB`, а где нет.

Ниже несколько примеров, и мои мысли по поводу что есть что:

```
int i = 0, x = 1;
int a[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

i = ++i + ++i; // UB
i = i++ + ++i; // UB
x = i++ + ++i; // ?? я думаю что UB 
x = i++ + i++; // OK
a[i] += i++;   // OK ??
a[++i] = i++;  // UB ??
a[++i] = ++i   // UB
i += ++i;      // UB
j += j;        // OK
```

За всё время я уяснил одно правило - *если в одном выражении значение объекта меняется более одного раза - `UB` чистой воды*, то есть понятно, что на каких-то платформах может и будет происходит то, что ожидается, но вопрос в том, что стандарт в таких случаях ничего не гарантирует - то есть либо говорится, что это `undefined behavour`, `unspecified behavour` либо `implementation defined behavour`.

Вопрос - могут ли возникнуть в этих примерах случаи, кроме `UB`?

Comment: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Вопрос критически отличается для С и С++.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Языки С и С++ фундаментально отличаются в одной важной детали: язык С++ старается максимально тщательно сохранять lvalue-ность результата выражения (lvalue-preserving language), а язык С наоборот - в большинстве случаев сразу беззаботно теряет lvalue-ность результата выражения (lvalue-discarding language)

```
int a = 0, b = 1;
a = b;     // lvalue в C++, rvalue в С
++b;       // lvalue в C++, rvalue в С
1 ? a : b; // lvalue в C++, rvalue в С
(a, b);    // lvalue в C++, rvalue в С
```

Эти свойства данных языков диктуют серьезные различия в их подходу к упорядочению (sequencing) операций в выражениях. Первый стандарт С++ (С++98) пытался игнорировать этот момент и придерживаться унаследованного напрямую из С подхода к упорядочению, но в конечном итоге эта модель была признана дефектной и существенно переработана. В процессе этой переработки в С++ появилась упорядоченность, которой ранее не было. Как следствие, некоторые выражения, которые формально порождали UB в C++98, получили вполне определенное поведение в C++11. А C++17 добавил еще больше отношений упорядочения в язык С++, тем самым еще более расширив круг выражений, поведение которых определено.

Поэтому ответ на вопрос о наличии UB в выражении может существенно отличаться между С и С++. Например, выражение

```
i = ++i;
```

порождает UB в С, но имеет совершенно определенное поведение в С++. Различие возникает по той причине, что в языке С++ гарантируется, что модификация переменной `i` под действием преинкремента произойдет *до* того, как будет завершено вычисление результата преинкремента. В языке С ничего подобного не гарантируется.

Правила "если в одном выражении значение объекта меняется более одного раза" не существовало никогда и нигде. Более-менее правильной формой этого правила будет "если *между парой соседних точек следования* значение объекта модифицируется более одного раза, то поведение не определено". Также не следует забывать вторую часть этого правила: "если между парой соседних точек следования значение объекта модифицируется, а также присутствует *независимое* чтение значения этого объекта, то поведение не определено". После переработки в С++11 эти правила, однако, стали применимы только к языку С, но не к языку С++ (см. пример выше).

Также стоит заметить, эти правила основаны на концепции *точки следования*, в то время как современные спецификации этих языков (как С++, так и С) решили отказаться от этой концепции и заменить ее концепцией *упорядочения* (*sequencing*, *sequenced before*, *sequenced after*). Но, еще раз, в языке С эти правила по-прежнему достаточно точно отражают ситуацию с UB в выражениях.

Новое же правило, применимое как в С, так и в С++, звучит так

> Если побочный эффект, воздействующий на скалярный объект, неупорядочен (unsequenced) по отношению к другому побочному эффекту, воздействующему на этот же скалярный объект, или по отношению к вычислению значения этого же скалярного объекта, то поведение не определено.

Различия же между С и С++ сводятся к отличающимся гарантиям того, что является упорядоченным (sequenced), а что нет (unsequenced). Упорядоченность оговаривается в описаниях конкретных операторов языка.

В ваших примерах

```
i = ++i + ++i; // UB и в С, и в С++
i = i++ + ++i; // UB и в С, и в С++
x = i++ + ++i; // UB и в С, и в С++
x = i++ + i++; // UB и в С, и в С++
a[i] += i++;   // UB и в С, и в С++11, все в порядке в С++17
a[++i] = i++;  // UB и в С, и в С++11, все в порядке в С++17
a[++i] = ++i   // UB и в С, и в С++11, все в порядке в С++17
i += ++i;      // UB в С, все в порядке в С++11 (?), все в порядке в С++17
j += j;        // OK
```

(Я не уверен в своей трактовке `i += ++i`. `A += B` определено через `A = A + B`, но `i = i + ++i` - это UB и в С++. Но подозреваю, что ситуацию спасает то, что `A` в `A += B` вычисляется только один раз.)

Comment: `a[i] += i++;` и 3 следующих - вроде с Си++ 17 не UB, т. к. левая часть присваивания обязана вычисляться до правой.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, точно. С++17 внес еще ряд дополнительных упорядочений. Только наоборот "The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.", т.е. правая часть обязана вычисляться до левой. Добавил замечание в ответ, спасибо.

Comment: Точно, перепутал :) А куда Си++ 14 потерялось в _"UB и в С, и в С++11, все в порядке в С++17"?_

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я навскидку не знаю, есть ли отличия в этом отношении между С++14 и С++11. Поэтому упоминаю только "этапные" стандарты. То есть С++11 означает "С++11 и далее, до С++17 (не включая последний)". Могу, конечно, упускать что-то из С++14.

Comment: Интересная трактовка. Потому что лично я эту запись прочитал как "UB и в [всех версиях] С, и в Си++11 [и ранее], все в порядке в Си++17 [и новее]" - получилось что-то странное в виде потерянного стандарта)))

Comment: а что есть точки следования ? я так пониманию это там, где заканчивается выражение точкой запятой ?

Comment: @ampawd: В классической системе (C89/90, C++98) расположение точек следования оговаривается для каждой ситуации отдельно. Это совсем не обязательно `;`. Точка следования есть в конце вычисления каждого *полного* выражения (но там не обязательно будет `;`); в конце каждого полного декларатора; на каждом операторе `,`, `&&`, `||`; после вычисления условия в `?:`; перед входом в функцию; перед выходом из функции; и т.д. и т.п. В стандарте С99 есть "Приложение C" (Annex C), где перечислены все места, в которых располагаются точки следования.

Comment: @AnT, "что в языке С++ гарантируется, что модификация переменной i под действием преинкремента произойдет до того, как будет завершено вычисление результата преинкремента." Это верно потому, что `++i` эквивалентен `i+=1`???

Comment: @wololo: И в С и в С++ `++i` всегда определялось через `i += 1`, а последнее в свою очередь - через `i = i + 1`. Однако в С++11 появилась дополнительная гарантия того, что определение значения-результата оператора присваивания делается только после того, как физически произошла запись в левую часть. В С++98 такой гарантии не было. Именно благодаря этой новой гарантии выражение `i = ++i` (эквивалентно `i = (i = i + 1)`) получило определенное поведение в С++11.