# Почему данный код выводит число 13?

Tags: javascript, инкремент

Объясните пожалуйста, почему данный код выводит число 13?

```
var i = 5;
i = ++i + ++i;
console.log(i); // 13
```

Comment: вы случайно не из мема увидели?, хд https://vk.cc/8opdUS

Comment: Посмотрите также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679815

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`++i` - это преинкремент. Он вычисляется перед использованием переменной.

Т.е, вычислилось первое `++i`, в `i` теперь `6`, выражение теперь `6 + (++6)`. Потом вычислили второе `++i`, в `i` теперь `7`. Потом сложили `6 + 7`, получили `13`.

С другой стороны, к примеру, если взять постинкремент `i++`.

После `i = i++ + i++;` в `i` будет `11`, т.к. постинкремент вычисляется после использования переменной.

Т.е, подставилось в выражение, вычислилось первое `i++`, в `i` теперь `6`, получили выражение `5 + (6++)`. Потом второе `i++`, в `i` было 6, оно и подставилось, стало `5 + 6`, после чего `i` стало равно `7`. Cложили `5 + 6`, получили `11`.

Comment: +1 отлично объяснили, любой, кто будет пытаться разобраться с этим вопросом имеет возможность прочитать уже разжеванную инфо.

Comment: Первый вариант очевидный, второй кажется запутанным. Наверное во избежание подобной путаницы желательно всегда использовать ++i по возможности?

Comment: Не согласен. И первый и второй очевидный. Просто с практикой вы понимаете где какой вариант вам нужнее. Все от ситуации зависит. Хотя честно признаюсь, я когда это все учил, именно на этом моменте у меня были проблемы.

Comment: @VladSpirin просто зачастую люди используют обычный вариант `++i` (в тех же циклах), и редко в комплексных выражениях. Поэтому, даже матёрые разработчики на этом моменте могут залипнуть )

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf главное понять концепцию. Это как и с теоремами в геометрии. Если понимаешь принцип, вывести/вычислить потом можно самому.

Comment: @Suvitruf я не понял часть с постинкрементами.Можно было по номерам обяснить.То есть 1 пункт это делает то 2 пунт то делает это и т.д.А так ответ хороший дал плюсик .

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Сначала выполняется "первый" i++, потом "второй". Лишь потом складывается.