# Почему выводит 4, а не 2?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {

    int a(2);
    std::cout << ((--a) * (++a)) << std::endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: А почему вдруг 2?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Понять где undefined behavour в арифметических выражениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679815/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-undefined-behavour-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]` — (c) GCC
>
> `warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'a' [-Wunsequenced]` — (c) Clang

Так делать нельзя. Изменение переменной два раза "в одном месте" (грубо говоря) вызывает неопределенное поведение, и результат выполнения такой программы может быть любым.

Подробнее можно прочитать вот тут: [**Order of evaluation**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

А еще здесь: [Понять где undefined behavour в арифметических выражениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679815/)
и здесь: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

---

Попробую кратко объяснить.

Если у вас есть выражение вида `A * B`, то `A` не обязательно будет вычислено до `B`. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>

int f1()
{
    std::cout << '1';
    return 1;
}

int f2()
{
    std::cout << '2';
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    int x = f1() * f2();
}
```

Этот код может напечатать `12` или `21`, в зависимости от желания левой пятки компилятора.

(Так же ведут себя `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, ..., но не `=`, `<<`, `>>`, `&&`, `||`, ... - подробности по самой верхней ссылке.)

Казалось бы, в случае `++a * --a` не должно быть важно, какой операнд вычисляется первым. Но:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. — [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Перевод:

> Если побочный эффект<sup>1</sup>, действующий на скалярную переменную<sup>2</sup>, не упорядочен<sup>3</sup> относительно другого побочного эффекта, действующего на ту же переменную, то поведение не определено.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> Здесь это означает изменение значения переменной `a` в результате вычисления `++a` или `--a`.
>
> <sup>2</sup> Т.е. на числовую переменную, а не на объект класса или что-то еще; здесь - на `a`.
>
> <sup>3</sup> Unsequenced - то есть может произойти до, после, или даже одновременно.

Comment: Могу ли я принудительно расставить порядок действий для компилятора? К примеру, int x = (f1()) * f2()

Comment: @llollcat Нет, здесь скобки ничего не поменяют. Можно так: `int a = f1(); int b = f2(); int x = a * b;` - тогда точно в нужном порядке посчитает.

Answer (score -7):

Потому что вы используете предекрименты и преинкременты в выражении взаимодействуя с целочисленной переменной "a".
получается 2 * 2 = 4

цитата

> Согласно спецификации языка, разница между пре- и постинкрементом состоит в том, что при вычислении выражения значением результат является в одном случае старое, а в другом — новое значение инкрементируемой переменной. В случае простого применения в форме x++; (например, такое часто встречается в циклах) возвращаемое значение не используется, и смысл обеих форм строго одинаков, так что они компилируются в одинаковый объектный код.

В таком случае, взаимодействие с переменной "а" будет происходить изначально, когда а = 2 если вы используете пре-инкременты и пре-декрименты