# Странность ввода с++

Tags: c++, io, ввод, std

Если запустить код:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a,b;
  //cin>>a;
  a=3;
  b= ++a * a++;
  cout<<b;

    return  0;
}
```

,то программа выдает 20.
Но если раскомментировать строку с cin>>a; то программа выводит 16,хотя в значении переменной "а" после 7-й строки кода в обоих случаях будет 3.
С чем это связано?

Comment: какой компилятор?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Понять где undefined behavour в арифметических выражениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679815/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-undefined-behavour-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто вот такое выражение -

```
++a * a++;
```

является *неопределенным поведением*. И компилятор может увеличивать и умножать значения по-разному в разных ситуациях - это его дело, как поступать. В одном случае ему удобнее увеличить до 4, перемножить, потом еще раз увеличить и дать 16. В другом - увеличить, запомнить, увеличить второй раз, перемножить 4 на 5, дать 20.

Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное, такое противоречивое всё - как девица в "Покровских воротах"... :)