# Разница между способами размещения объекта по конкретному адресу

Tags: c++, память

```
int n = 0;
// первый способ размещения символа по адресу
char* pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n);
*pch = 'a';

// второй способ
char* pnew = new (&n)char('a');

// проверка
if (pch == pnew)
   cout  << n;
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу между размещениями первым и вторым способом. Если ее нет, то тогда для чего нужно существование `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Первое — undefined behavior, второе, думаю, тоже. Разницы нет, и то, и другое неправильно.

Comment: тогда не понимаю для чего нужен был вообше reinterpret_cast ?  Пусть использовали бы new  и static_cast?..

Comment: А вот это хорошая тема для отдельного вопроса, думаю.

Comment: VladD, добавил, давай поговорим?...

Comment: Я думаю, имеет смысл вопрос о `reinterpret_cast` задать отдельно. (И я сам не большой спец в C++, пусть специалисты лучше ответят.)

Comment: Отдельный вопрос, пожалуйся, не просто добавление к этому вопросу.

Comment: я недавно в сайте, поэтому просвятите меня, какая разница вопросы задаются отдельно или нет? Я же просто хочу получить ответ на вопрос, который у меня возник. Обьясните, чтоб я понел и впредь делал так как нужно

Comment: и думаю кому то не лень ставить минусы, какбудто для него это компьютерная игра  Когда голосуете, то обьясните что вы _ многоуважаемый  эксперт нашли в вопросе такого, что  не дает вас просто  просмотреть другие.  Особенно если не вашего ума дело отвечать на такой вопрос

Comment: lдело не в том нравится мне он или нет - лично мне они вообше пока  не понадобились, а дело в простом желании знать. То что это нужно делать только при крайной необходимости и тщательно скрыть, это все понятно.. Еще раз прочитайте суть моего вопроса

Comment: кстати union использовать тоже не советуется...но вы просто не понимаете вопрос или не знаете ответа

Comment: отвечают, потом удаляют свой ответ, ставят минусы и уходят _  и тут показываем  свою дисциплину...

Comment: @VladD, можете пояснить почему первое UB? Насколько мне известно, к памяти [можно](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.8) обращаться через `char*`

Comment: Вопрос о смысле существования `reinterpret_cast` уже [есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716240/%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-reinterpret-cast).

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: Хм, и правда. Наверное, всё же первое — не UB. Я забыл, что `char*` — особый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу: не буду говорить об UB - откровенно говоря, не вижу (особенно в вашем случае, для `char`) для него причин... но это одно из моих слабых мест. Самому будет интересно выcлушать, *почему* здесь UB. Если из-за strict aliasing - то вроде как раз через `char*` разрешено обращение...

Как человек более практический :), скажу, что основное отличие будет проявляться тогда, когда это будут не POD, а какие-то более интересные случаи - например, объекты класса. Пример, кусочки из которого здесь, полностью лежит по адресу https://ideone.com/RvQSax

В первом случае мы имеем присваивание, и вызывается именно оператор присваивания:

```
long long L;
Test * t = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(&L);
*t = Test(5);
```

Главная беда в том, что присваивание выполняется просто месту в памяти, так что если оператор присваивания будет заниматься сначала удалением объекта, которому присваиваем - мы таки получим неприятностей... А если там лежал таки объект с нетривиальным деструктором - то проблем будет еще больше.

```
long long M;
Test * u = new(&M) Test(6);
```

Этот способ куда корректнее - потому что размещающий оператор `new` предполагает наличие *неинициализированной* памяти, в которой с помощью конструктора нужно разместить объект (ну, как если бы память была выделена). Никаких действий с якобы размещенным до этого в этой памяти объектом не производится.
Но! Все равно остается старая проблема - если там реально был объект с нетривиальным деструктором - то будут проблемы.

P.S. Может, @VladD имел в виду именно это, говоря об UB?

Comment: Ага, я забыл об особой роли `char*`.

Comment: Harry и  VladD, вы как всегда отвечаете корректно и ясно, Приятно, что есть такие пользователи