# Доступ к структуре через unsigned char

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Пусть есть структура `S` следующего вида:

```
    struct S 
    {
        short a;
        char b;
    };
```

И размер `sizeof(short)` равен 2, а размер `sizeof(S)` равен 4 (т.е. в структуре есть один padding byte).

Вопрос 1. Является ли корректным с точки зрения стандарта языка такой код:

```
    S st;

    st.a = 0; st.b = 0;
    unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&st);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(st); ++i)
        unsigned int tmp = p[i];
```

Вопрос 2. Если код корректен, то гарантируется ли, что в ситуации, когда указатель `p` указывает на padding byte структуры `S`, в переменную `tmp` будет записано некоторое целочисленное значение из отрезка `[0; UCHAR_MAX]` или допускаются какое-нибудь менее очевидное поведение, например, генерация исключения.

---

Дополнение.

Действительно, если есть объект тривиально-копируемого типа `T`, то составляющие его байты могут быть безопасно скопированы (например, с помощью `memcpy`) в массив `char`, `unsigned char` или `std::byte` (и обратно). Также можно скопировать некоторый объект тривиально-копируемого типа в другой объект этого же типа (с помощью того же самого `memcpy`, например.)

Однако, в пункте 11.6/12 ([n4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)) есть занятный пример:

```
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char d = c; // OK, d has an indeterminate value
    int e = d; // undefined behavior
```

Не является ли мой пример, в **некотором** смысле, эквивалентом этого примера из стандарта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Да, каст к `char*` и `unsigned char*` разрешен (а каст к другим типам запрещен [правилами aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503265/177684))

2) Нет для `int`.

Паддинг можно читать-писать (иначе memcpy сломался бы).

Однако, [стандарт разрешает читать *indeterminate value* типа `[unsigned] char`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12.2) в присваиваниях где левая стророна это `l-value` типа `[unsigned] char`, но запрещает присваивать например `int`.

(При этом неясно, считается ли что паддинг может иметь *indeterminate value*)

Comment: Хм, то есть, гарантировано, что паддинг не имеет trap representation? Это значит, что конструктор обязан его инициализировать?

Comment: Ага, вижу. Спасибо!