# И снова о доступе к объектам через указатели на char

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Вопрос 1.

В стандарте языка есть такое понятие как [*similar types* (conv.qual/2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2). Являются ли типы `unsigned char` и `int` *similar*? (Я полагаю, что нет, однако, если да, то хотелось бы узнать почему?)

Вопрос 2.

В разделе стандарта языка, описывающего аддитивные операции (в частности арифметику указателей), есть интересный пункт [expr.add/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#6):

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions `P` or `Q` have type “pointer to *cv* `T`”, **where `T` and the array element type are not similar**, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: In particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type. — end note ]

Пусть есть следующий код:

```
int mass[2];
unsigned char *p = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(mass);

p = p + 1;  //UB?
```

Является ли приведённый код неопределённым поведением? Если нет, то почему?

(По-моему, приведённый код в точности соответствует приведённой цитате из стандарта. Этот вопрос возник у меня отчасти потому, что когда речь заходит о *strict aliasing rules*, то всегда оговаривается, что к объектам можно получить доступ через `char`/`unsigned char`. Но о каком доступе к объекту может идти речь, если нельзя наращивать указатель?)

Вопрос 3.

Если поведение кода в вопросе 2 не определено, то как реализовать свой `memcpy`?

Comment: гуглите [strict aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-strict-aliasing). Если в двух словах, то к памяти можно обращаться только через указатель такого типа, что там на самом деле лежит, или `char*`. Поэтому свой `memcpy` можно реализовать без особых изысков

Comment: Ответ исправить не получилось, удаляю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Речь в [[conv.qual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#2) идёт о разложении сложных типов, являющихся указателями или массивами с перемежающими квалификаторами `const`, `volatile`. Причём наличие условия `n > 0` говорит о том, что эти типы должны быть как минимум второго уровня, условно, указатель на указатель. При всём этом базовый тип `U` в разложении должен быть одинаковым. Понятно, что базовые типы `int` и `unsigned char` таковыми не являются. Немного примеров схожих (*similar*) и не схожих типов можно посмотреть [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) (раздел *Type aliasing*).

Далее в цитате, которую Вы приводите, упоминается пример, говорящий, что нельзя итерироваться по контейнеру элементов производного типа, имея указатель на базовый тип:

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

D a[10];
B* p = a;
p++;       // породит значение, которое может не указывать на валидный объект типа D
```

Доступ же к объектам через указатель на `char`, `unsigned char` или `std::byte` [явно разрешен](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11.8). То есть проблем с реализацией `memcpy` не будет.

Comment: Пример, с указателем на базовый тип начинается со слов "In particular", что означает, насколько я понимаю, "в частности". То есть в приведённой цитате **не** говорится, что она распространяется **только** на ситуации, когда пытаемся "итерироваться по контейнеру элементов производного типа, имея указатель на базовый тип". К тому же, приведённая в вопросе цитата **не** запрещает получать доступ к контейнеру посредством указателя на `char`. Она явно запрещает прибавлять (вычитать) к указателю целые числа, если указатель указывает на тип, который не является _схожим_ с типом элементов массива.

Comment: @wololo я думаю "In particular" приведён как наиболее частый случай ошибки, ибо не требуется **явного** преобразования указателей. Если не использовать наследование, то можно в моём примере заменить указатель: `int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(a);`, это также будет подпадать по условие "не схожих" типов, но каст уже становится явным со всеми вытекающими. При это я не думаю, что сама арифметика указателей может привести к каким-либо проблемам, если не обращаться к данным по результирующему адресу.

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить (дабы не было недопонимания): как вы считаете, типы `unsigned char` и `int` являются similar или не являются similar?

Comment: @wololo согласно определению *similar types* они таковыми не являются.

Comment: Хорошо, я рад, что наши мнения совпадают :). И да, я тоже не считаю, что арифметика указателей может привести к каким-либо проблемам. Однако, я не вижу ни одной причины, почему код, приведённый в вопросе, не должен являться UB с точки зрения приведённой в вопросе цитаты из стандарта. И это меня беспокоит. Как вы считаете, чисто формально, попадает ли код в вопросе под действие цитаты из стандарта, приведённой в вопросе?

Comment: @wololo учитывая появившийся ответ VladD, скажу, что "нет", не попадает.