# Двойной static_cast через void*, вместо reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

Некоторые авторы используют двойное преобразование через `void*` с помощью `static_cast`, вида:

```
long* px;
char* p = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(px));
```

вместо `reinterpret_cast`:

```
long* px;
char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(px);
```

В чем преимущество/недостатки первого варианта?

Comment: Сейчас явно будет комментарий о strict aliasing :)

Comment: Даже если переводят его, а не в него? Вроде [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503266/195342) написано наоборот? Или я опять не так понял?

Comment: второй вариант более безопасен

Comment: @ARHovsepyan кмк, второй опаснее, т.к. в первый кроме указателя ничего не подставишь по ошибке.

Comment: Да какой компилятор не возьми - код-то один и тот же... https://godbolt.org/g/NBBj3S

Comment: Vladimir, в  С++ я не профессионал, но  насколько я понимаю статически  размещать тип по некому конкретному адресу менее безопасен...

Comment: Приведение одного указательного типа на объект к другому указательному типу на объект посредством `reinterpret_cast` по-определению осуществляется через двойной `static_cast`. [Пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)

Comment: Например [С++ core guidelines рекомендуют не использовать `reinterpter_cast`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Pro-type-reinterpretcast). Собственно там рекомендуют по возможности отказываться от кастования, но `reinterpter_cast` идет первым пунктом.

Comment: @VTT Верно. Но про static_cast для указателей (кроме downcast) там же нет вроде рекомендаций?

Answer (score 5):

Двойное преобразование `static_cast` с преобразованием в `void*` на первом шаге ограничивает возможный тип аргумента указателем, и не позволяет использовать в качестве него целый тип. Пример:

```
int  i = 42;
int* p = nullptr;

// Различное поведение при использовании целого аргумента    
static_cast<short*>(static_cast<void*>(i)); // ошибка компиляции
reinterpret_cast<short*>(i);                // ok

// Эквивалентны при использовании аргумента указателя
static_cast<short*>(static_cast<void*>(p)); // ok
reinterpret_cast<short*>(p);                // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то один `static_cast` даже лишний, можно определить шаблонную функцию специально для указателей, нельзя записать в строчку, как вариант с двумя `static_cast`, зато понятно, что имеется в виду.

```
template <typename U,typename T>
inline U* pointer_cast(T* p) 
{ 
    void* t = p; 
    return static_cast<U*>(t); 
}
```