# синтаксический аналог memcpy

Tags: c++

помогите сделать без memcpy то же самое:

```
char in[10] = {0};
int value = 13415;
memcpy(in, &value, sizeof(value));
```

Comment: Чем вас memcpy не устроил?

Comment: @Duoxx, хотелось одной строчкой вместо трех... и без ub

Comment: Какая разница сколько строчек? На машинный код это никак не повлияет.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Как минимум GCC и Clang даже **с выключенной оптимизацией** генерируют одинаковый код (с точностью до порядка инструкций) что для memcpy, что для присвоения через указатели. Пруф: https://godbolt.org/g/zTtAsj На Visual Studio не проверял.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78884/discussion-on-question-by-xperious---memcpy).

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с переинтерпретацией массива `char [10]` как lvalue типа `int` при помощи каста (`(int &) in = value;` и т.п.) - это грубое нарушение strict aliasing и неопределенное поведение в обоих языках, как уже было сказано в комментариях. Поэтому тут либо `memcpy`, либо его рукописный аналог.

Есть еще вариант, который делает *почти* то же самое, без `memcpy`

```
union { char in[10]; int value; } u = { 0 };
u.value = 12345;
```

после чего сразу смотрим в `u.in` и видим там результат.

Проблема, однако, в том, что использовать `union` таким способом формально разрешено именно в С, но не в С++. Но на это еще можно закрыть глаза. А вот на `(int &) in = value;` закрыть глаза нельзя.

Comment: И почему одно UB лучше другого?

Comment: @Qwertiy: О каком "другом UB" идет речь? Вариант с `union` в С не нарушает правил strict aliasing и не порождает UB (если считать, что `char` не имеет trap representations). То есть никакого UB тут нет.

Comment: @Ant, а если сделать так?
(reinterpret_cast<volatile std::int32_t*>(in))[0] = value;
я так понимаю, strict aliasing страшен в оптимизациях. а так то ничего плохого в нем нету, поэтому может volatile чуть менее опасно будет использовать?

Comment: @AnT, но для Си++ это UB - ты же сам сказал. Тогда почему UB с union'ом лучше, чем UB с приведением указателя?

Comment: У меня такой же вопрос, чем это UB лучше reinterpret_cast? Расчет на то, что если так было можно в С, то компиляторы С++ не станут это ломать?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Во-первых, расчет на то, что рано или поздно (если не уже сейчас - не проверял) эта часть спецификации С для некоторых классов типов будет перенесена в С++. И, во-вторых, да, именно на то, что "компиляторы С++ не станут это ломать".

Comment: @Qwertiy: "Лучше" хотя бы тем, что примеров UB через нарушение strict aliasing - несчетное множество, а примеров UB с type punning через `union` - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте цикл:

```
char in[10] = {0};
int value = 13415;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof value; i++)
    in[i] = ((char*)&value)[i];
```

Но если есть возможность, просто возьмите `memcpy()`. Цикл ничем не лучше, а если включите оптимизацию, то и цикл, и `memcpy()` все равно превратятся в одно и то же.

В соседнем ответе предлагают `(*(int*)(in))=value;` (он же `(int&)in = value;`), но это нарушает strict aliasing и приводит к неопределенному поведению. Так лучше не делать.

Comment: Цикл на 4 байта.... Это очень нерационально в 10 раз медленнее будет а то и больше.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков можно переделать на 32 бита, будет рациональнее :-D

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Поэтому и стоит использовать memcpy

Comment: Когда вижу `sizeof` без скобочек меня аж трисёт.

Comment: Зачем цикл, когда можно в одну процессорную команду скопировать как в  соседнем ответе. Всегда так пишу и проблем ниразу не было.

Comment: Проблемы начнутся если в массив не влезет. Если уж серавно самый быстрый вариант не нравиться, то брать сразу itoa и не складировать компактно биты, если на скорость с++ наплевать то и на память можно забить.

Comment: @nick_n_a Это будет работать ровно до тех пор, пока какой-нибудь шибко умный компилятор не начнет ломать этот код при оптимизации.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков *"Это очень нерационально"* После оптимизации будет вполне рационально.

Comment: @alexolut А меня вот трясет, когда после sizeof ставят лишние скобки, когда они не нужны. :)

Comment: В частных случаях не нужны, но для единообразия я предпочитаю ставить всегда. Например, для `long long` уже без скобок не прокатит.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, это уж вопрос стиля. Я предпочитаю ставить, только когда нужны.

Comment: @nick_n_a Вот вам пример из истории: В свое время [Chromium перестал нормально собираться на GCC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893251/why-does-the-enhanced-gcc-6-optimizer-break-practical-c-code/36916651), потому что новый модный оптимизатор GCC 6 превращал `if (this == 0)` в `if (false)` (в полном соответствии со стандартом), и разработчики хромиума попали впросак, потому что положились на неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @alexolut: Должно быть с точность до наоборот: предпочитать надо `sizeof oбъект`, а не `sizeof(тип)` и при этом не замусоривать код ненужными скобками в первом варианте. "Для long long без скобок не прокатит" - не потому, что в `long long` два слова, а потому, что `long long` - это *тип*. `sizeof(тип)`, еще раз, надо по возможности избегать. Предпочитайте `sizeof oбъект`.

Comment: @AnT да, с типом действительно нужны скобки. Т.к. версию без скобок не использую, то и позабыл этот нюанс. Всё таки оператор `sizeof` не позволяет писать слитно с аргументом как, скажем, `+`. И функциональная запись выглядит для меня более естественной, чем обязательный пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Можно со сдвигами поизвращаться

```
int value = 13415;
char in[10] = { value, value >> 8, value >> 16, value >> 24 };
```

Comment: 1. big/little indian. 2. другие размеры int'а

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, при желании можно попробовать завернуть в шаблон и учесть архитектуру и размеры инта. Это просто чтобы показать, что такой способ тоже есть.

Answer (score -1):

```
(*(int*)(in))=value;
```

Должно сработать.

Comment: Так можно. И это копирует значение.

Comment: Хм-м. И это не UB?

Comment: я так понимаю, это одно и то же (reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(in))[0] = value; ?

Comment: @D-side Да, неопределенное поведение из-за нарушения strict aliasing.

Comment: @xperious Да. Еще короче можно сделать `(int&)in = value;`, но это опять же неопределенное поведение. Не делайте так.

Comment: в char же исключение из strict aliasing разве нет?

Comment: @pavel Исключение только в одну сторону работает, если я правильно помню. К любому типу можно обращаться через `char*`, да. Но к массиву чаров через произвольный указатель нельзя. (Разве что после placement-new.)

Comment: @VTT а чем это глобально отличается от побайтового копирования объекта? под капотом memcpy так же и работает, разве нет?

Comment: @pavel Тем, что формально одно - это UB, а второе - нет. Вот и все. :)

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Вот, почитайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503265/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-strict-aliasing

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Не, volatile не спасает: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981827/strict-pointer-aliasing-is-access-through-a-volatile-pointer-reference-a-solu

Comment: Я по любому не буду использовать memcpy или другой цикл, если этот код используется часто. С++ мне нужен для скорости. Я скорее -fno-strict-aliasing добавлю или просто отрублю проверку.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Как минимум GCC и Clang даже **с выключенной оптимизацией** генерируют одинаковый код (с точностью до порядка инструкций) что для memcpy, что для присвоения через указатели. Пруф: https://godbolt.org/g/zTtAsj На Visual Studio не проверял. Так что потери в скорости быть не должно.

Comment: У меня не оптимизировал.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78885/discussion-on-answer-by-----memcpy).