# Как работает адресная арифметика?

Tags: c++, c

```
int arr[4] = {4,5,6,3};
float * b =(float*)arr;
int * b1 = (int*)arr;
cout << b + 1<<" "<< b1+1<<" "<<b1[1]-b[1]<<endl;
```

Я не понимаю,почему мы присваиваем указателю типа float указатель на int-массив и когда мы прибавляем ему единицу он прибавляется на sizeof(int) а не sizeof(float),ведь тип указателя float а не int.Я думал адресная арифметика считается относительно базового типа указателя.

И почему b1[1]-b[1] возвращает 5 а не 0?

Comment: *"прибавляется на sizeof(int) а не sizeof(float)"* А что, у вас `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)`? *"почему b1[1]-b[1] возвращает 5 а не 0"* Может вы хотели написать `&b1[1]-&b[1]`? Но еще нужно будет касты добавить.

Comment: HolyBlackCat,нет,именно b1[1]-b[1], b1[1] равно же 4 ровно как и b[1]

Comment: `5.f` вряд ли хранится в памяти в том же виде, что и `5` ([вот тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) можно почитать про представление чисел с плавающей точкой). Плюс, `b1[1]` вообще [нарушает strict aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503265/215103) и вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нарушает `b1[1]` или `b[1]`?

Comment: @Harry Ой, `b` конечно...