# Генерация полностью рандомных чисел в C++

Tags: c++

В с++ хочу сгенерировать рандомное число, но число, которое генерируется с помощью функции rand() с каждым запуском не меняется. Так вот вопрос, как сгенерировать поистине рандомное число, которое с каждым запуском программы будет регенерироваться?

Comment: Используйте API TPM или или Intel DRNG.

Comment: Начните с `srand(time(NULL))`.

Comment: Но только один раз в начале работы программы! а то некоторые умельцы начинают вызывать перед каждым вызовом `rand()`...

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что   выделяя динамическую память операционная система  обычно  не повторяется с адресом: то можно  значение этого адреса использовать как зерно распределения, как альтернативный способ:

```
class Seed {
    union {
        const char* p;
        const unsigned n;
    };
public:
    Seed() : p(new char) {}
    operator unsigned() const
    {
        return n;
    }
    ~Seed() { delete p; }
};
```

И пример применения:

```
srand(Seed());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    cout << rand() % 100 << ' ';
```

Просто можно не подключать дополнительный файл.

Comment: Поведение программы не определено, так как нарушает [strict aliasing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503265).

Comment: В адресном пространстве процесса адрес первого выделенного объекта всегда будет один и тот же. Физически объект может оказаться где угодно, но операционная система скрывает этот факт от процесса с помощью такой штуки как трансляция адресов (виртуальная память).

Comment: @wololo, не могу согласиться _ объединение тут не причем и речь только про простых программах, а не для повсеместного использования