# как по красивому сделать класс ARGB?

Tags: c++, union, rgb

вариант1:

```
struct _color
{
    uchar b, g, r, a;
    _color(uint c) { *((uint*)this) = c; }
};
```

предупреждает, что a,r,g,b не инициализированы
вариант2:

```
union _color2
{
    struct
    {
        uchar b, g, r, a;
    };
    uint c;
    _color2(uint c_) { c = c_; }
};
```

предупреждает, что структура без имени.
Хочется чтобы было просто, и без предупреждений! как можно по другому?
важно! конструктор должен быть по быстроте такой же как и в 1,2 варианте.

Comment: В первом примере следует удалить `*((uint*)this) = c;` и инициализировать поля.

Comment: У приведенного кода есть проблема с порядком байт и разнообразными паддингами. В целом - попытка оптимизировать за компилятор. Но если очень хочется - memcpy  в помощь.

Comment: во втором случае ISO C++ запрещает анонимные структуры. Надо дать имя типу структуры или имя переменной данного типа.

Comment: инициализировать поля - полагаться на случай, что компилятор правильно оптимизирует. а memcpy - вообще вызов функции. конструктор должен быть максимально быстрым!

Comment: ага, вот оно - преждевременная пессимизация. memcpy давно уже "магическая функция" и компилятор ее эффективно заменяет на код. И главное правило - не пытайтесь обмануть компилятор (в коде это как раз и происходит) - он поймает и накажет. Пишите максимально простой код и все будет работать. Потом профайлер и искать слабые места.

Comment: По-моему, надо массивом, тогда будет более надежно?

Comment: Оба варианта вызывают неопределённое поведение, т.к. нарушено [правило строгих псевдонимов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503265).